Optical drive doesn't show in Ubuntu Budgie 22.04
I've had ubuntu for 2 decades now and I believe that I've always had trouble with optical drives. This one machine is hooked up to my TV so that I can watch anything on it. I had built it specifically with an optical drive so that I could watch dvds on it. I know it's old tech but I've got a bunch of personal camcorder DVDs that I can't watch because even though I swapped the drive with a new one it still won't work. It boots ok from a live cd so the drive and cable should be OK. I looked in /dev and there is no cd or dvd. I really need this fixed.
System is running Ubuntu Budgie 22.04

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0. Read man journalctl.

thanks but that's far too complicated for me.that manual is huge.
